# What's the verb for "to drink small amounts of drink"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What's the verb for "to drink small amounts of drink" (especially to enjoy it as slowly and long as possibly)? What's the drinking equivalent of "nibble"?

Comment: Did you try googling for "drink slowly", etc?

Comment: @Fiksdal Did you? A Google search for [to drink small amounts of drink especially to enjoy it as slowly and long as possibly](https://www.google.com/search?q=to+drink+small+amounts+of+drink+especially+to+enjoy+it+as+slowly+and+long+as+possibly) returns one decent result, a MacMillan Dictionary page called [To drink in a particular way - synonyms or related words](https://www.google.com/amp/www.macmillandictionary.com/license/amp/thesaurus-category/british/to-drink-in-a-particular-way),  which lists 28 words but does not include *savor* or other synonyms such as *imbibe*.

Comment: A Google search for "drink slowly" returns the same deficient MacMillan page and a bunch of crossword puzzle clue pages, and to the M-W thesaurus, which includes a dozen or so synonyms, including *sip*; but an investigator who happens to  click on *sip* won't find *savor* listed as a synonym or even as a "related word". Thesaurus dot com lists two dozen synonyms for *to drink* but savor is not among them. Is an investigator expected to look up the definitions of  two dozen synonyms in the hope that one of them might mean *drink slowly*? Even if he does, he won't find *savor*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Yes, I did try googling that. I did not mean to imply very much by it, I merely wanted to know what research OP had done. And yes, askers here are indeed expected to do some research before asking, and to include that in OP when relevant. (Failing to do so is actually a canned close-reason here.) This question as asked strikes me as perhaps better suited for ELL. Anyway, not a big deal.

Comment: @Fiksdal "drink slowly" doesn't necessarily imply "drink small amounts" imo. I can take large mouthfuls of water slowly when I take med.

Comment: @Vun Sure. Thus, "drink slowly, **etc**". I didn't mean to imply that this wasn't a good question, I was just wondering whether you had done any research prior to asking. For example, checking dictionaries, translations of terms from one's mother tounge, synonyms, etc. and *then* asking.

Comment: Actually, this question may be off-topic after all. Normally I don't expect to get useful results on Google if I have to use a long phrase to describe the concept I'm looking for. In fact, I've failed several times when I tried to search for "slit skirt", "earmuffs", "throw a tantrum", "repeat a year", etc. It's totally understandable on my part if the question should be closed.

Comment: Is this a literal question, or more so a way of collecting euphemisms or synonyms so that an author (OP presumably) would be able to include more "interesting" words in a story?  If the latter then words like `flirt`, `tickle`, or `taste` could be used, no?

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw I think it would have been on-topic if you included the research you had done :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**sip** is the common word, but it does not denote 'to enjoy it as slowly and long as possibly'. For that, I suggest **savor** (UK: savour)

> Taste (good food or drink) and enjoy it to the full
>
> He has dinner and actually savors the wine, rather than drinking to get drunk.

1.1

> Enjoy or appreciate (something pleasant) to the full, especially by lingering over it

([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/savour))

**sip**

> Drink (something) by taking small mouthfuls.
>
> ‘I sat sipping coffee’
> ‘she sipped at her tea’

([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/sip))

You can definitely savor a good cup of coffee. A difference is this: if your coffee is hot, you can use *she sipped her coffee because it was hot* but you wouldn't really say *she savored her coffee because it was hot*. You'd say *she savored her coffee because it was delicious*.

**sip** is also a occurs as a noun, meaning

> A small mouthful of liquid (Oxford)

And we say stuff like *take a sip* (very common) and *have a sip*. *She  took a sip of wine* is equal to *she sipped her wine (one time)*.

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sip) lists these synonyms for *sip* (verb):

*drink in, extract, imbibe, partake, quaff, sample, savor, sup, swallow, taste, toss*

Only *savor* includes the notion of enjoy as part of its definition. *[Quaff](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quaff)* means to 'drink (alcoholic beverages)  heartily' but does not include the sense of slow enjoyment. In fact, it can be more of an antonym, since 'drink heartedly' can entail drinking quickly.

Comment: Off-topic, maybe, but I always liked Terry Pratchett's definition of *quaff*: It's like drinking, but you spill more.

Comment: Love me some Pratchett @PatJ

Comment: I appreciate the valuable  usage of citations from reliable references in the answer. +1

Comment: Quick tip, "quaff" means to drink heartily, not exactly a synonym of "sip".

Comment: @Lizahrd I didn't list it as a synonym of *tip*, Thesaurus.com did. In fact it's more of an antonym, since drink heartedly can entail drinking  quickly.

Comment: @Alan Carmack Indeed, I just thought you might want to exclude it, as someone who reads this and doesn't know the definition might use it as a synonym for sip anyway.

Comment: I would add the use of "sip" as a noun, most often "take a sip", but also "drink in sips".

Comment: Yeah you're @Right :)  and I say that mostly because hours ago  I had thought of doing that. Anyway, it's done now.

Comment: Oh man! That's right! "sip"! How could I forget this?

Answer (score 20):

Another verb would be **nurse**. [From Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nurse?s=t), usage #11 as a verb:

to use, consume, or dispense very slowly or carefully:
*He nursed the one drink all evening.*

Comment: To me, *nurse* implies that he's making the drink last because a) he doesn't like it or b) he doesn't want to buy another. (Or, if it's an alcoholic drink, c) because he has to drive home and doesn't want to be drunk when he does.)

Comment: or d) he was born yesterday.

Comment: @PatJ I partly agree. To nurse is to proceed slowly with something. Usually this is associated with consuming small amounts, but amount is not really defined as small or otherwise. I would consider it a good answer, but I think sip is better.

Answer (score 12):

***[To sip](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/storm)*** conveys the idea:

> - to drink, taking only a very small amount at a time:
>
>   - *This tea is very hot, so sip it carefully. She slowly sipped (at) her wine.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

To Sup
"take (drink or liquid food) by sips or spoonfuls."

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=sup+define

Comment: Appropriate username.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the words sip and sup, you may want something else. I was thinking you could use a regular drinking word that could be used as what you are asking for *and* just the definition of "drink". Here are some examples:

> He drank his beverage [drop](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/droplet?s=t) by drop until it was drained.
>
> She took a [hint](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hint?s=t) of her coffee.
>
> They had a small [portion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/portion) of their precious water.

Hopefully these words don't go *too* far.

Comment: Your first two sample sentences are both rather unidiomatic. The first one is outright ungrammatical -- "he drank his beverage drop by drop" is slightly better.

Comment: @duskwuff Then I shall edit it.

Comment: "drop by drop of" is still not grammatical.